# Check if whole string contains same character

Tags: php, string, validation, unique

I want to check if a string contains a character repeated zero or more times, for example:

- If my string is `aaaaaa`, `bbbb`, `c` or `*****` it must return `true`.
- If it contains `aaab`, `cd`, or `**%***` it must return `false`.

In other words, if the string has 2 or more unique characters, it must return `false`.

How to go about this in PHP?

PS: Is there a way to do it without RegEx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could [`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) on every character then [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) the array for unique values.

```
if(count(array_count_values(str_split('abaaaa'))) == 1) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/760293

Comment: Nice answer, but could be more elegant if was as follow: `return count(array_count_values(str_split('abaaaa'))) == 1;`

Answer (score 5):

```
count(array_unique(explode('', string)) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: This will produce a warning `explode(): Empty delimeter`. Use `str_split` instead

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression with a back-reference:

```
if (preg_match('/^(.)\1*$/', $string)) {
    echo "Same characters";
}
```

Or a simple loop:

```
$same = true;
$firstchar = $string[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    if ($string[$i] != $firstchar) {
        $same = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strlen(str_replace($string[0], '', $string)) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it:

```
<?php

function str2Dec($string) {
    $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
    $hex = array_shift($hexstr);

    return hexdec($hex);
}

function isBoring($string) {
    return str2Dec($string) % str2Dec(substr($string, 0, 1)) === 0;
}

$string1 = 'tttttt';
$string2 = 'ttattt';

var_dump(isBoring($string1)); // => true
var_dump(isBoring($string2)); // => false
```

Obviously this works only in small strings because once it gets big enough, the INT will overflow and the mod will not produce the correct value. So, don't use this :) - posting it just to show a different idea from the usual ones.

Comment: For the poor folks who are not familiar with `unpack()` and `hexdec()`, could you [edit] your question to explain how this technique works (when it works)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the number of unique characters is greater than 1.  This will perform well even if the input string is empty: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4b2v9))

```
$string = 'aaaba';
var_export(
    strlen(count_chars($string, 3)) < 2   // false
);
```

Alternatively, you can trim the string by its first character, but this will  generate warnings/notices if the input string has no length.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4JWLm))

```
$string = 'aaaba';
var_export(
    !strlen(trim($string, $string[0]))   // false
);
```

p.s. Yes, you *could* use `!strlen(trim($string, @$string[0]))` to prevent warnings/notices caused by a zero-length string, but I avoid error suppression like the plague because it generally gives code a bad smell.

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `^(.)\1{1,}`

`^`: Starting of string

`(.)`: Match and capture single characted.

`\1{1,}`: using captured character one or more than once.

[For this you can use regex](https://regex101.com/r/iMlm6q/1)

**OR:**

[PHP code demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e0235bafa094b56410ef49d6dce70920dd91df4)

```
$string="bbbb";
if($length=strlen($string))
{
    substr_count($string,$string[0]);
    if($length==substr_count($string,$string[0]))
    {
        echo "Do something";
    }
}
```

Comment: `{1,}` is the same as `+`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks i know but most of times i use this instead of `+`.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Updated my post please check.